# how to predict execution time of a MapReduce job before its execution in Hadoop Yarn

Tags: facebook

How can we estimate the run time( i.e Expected Completion time) of a map reduce job in hadoop yarn?
The execution time of a MapReduce job is available after it completes. But i have not found any way to predict its execution time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well iterating through the individual steps of the job would give a better understanding of how the job is running. For instance, the initial parsing of the file could be assumed a factor of N, writing the files to the nodes may be another factor of N, and etc. I'm far from an expert but if you grab a better understanding of how MapReduce truly works then you can find it

All in all, it depends greatly on what job you are trying to accomplish.